# Tomcat 10 wont start with https

Tags: https, java-17, tomcat10

I am trying to migrate from Tomcat 9 to Tomcat 10, i have installed java 17 and tomcat 10, and i have been able to start it without a problem using only http but when added the jks that i had running on my Tomcat 9
installation i get the following error.
  `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no element SSLHostConfig found with hostName [_default_] corresponding to defaultSSLHostConfigName for the connector [https-jsse-nio-8443]`

here is my server.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="-1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!-- APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html
         AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               maxParameterCount="1000"
               />
   
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25"
enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100" scheme="https"
secure="true" clientAuth="false"
sslProtocol="TLS"
sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
allowUnsafeLegacyRenegotiation="false"
ciphers="TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"

                                 keystoreFile="c:\c.jks"
keystorePass="CARD24" server=" " />



    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               maxParameterCount="1000"
               />
    -->
    <!-- Define an SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 with HTTP/2
         This connector uses the NIO implementation. The default
         SSLImplementation will depend on the presence of the APR/native
         library and the useOpenSSL attribute of the AprLifecycleListener.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used regardless of
         the SSLImplementation selected. JSSE style configuration is used below.
    -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxParameterCount="1000"
               >
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <!--
    <Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
               address="::1"
               port="8009"
               redirectPort="8443"
               maxParameterCount="1000"
               />
    -->

    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

tried using p12 key store same error.

Comment: This is not programming or development, but your problem is not the jks (keystore) it is the configuration you apparently copied from 9 (which had it from <=8) unthinkingly; see the 6th para here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support "It is expected that Tomcat 10 will drop support for [most] SSL attributes in the Connector." -- and sure enough it did.

Comment: C&an you please provide a valid ssl config tag to be added in the server.xml

Comment: Not on StackOverflow, but your file already has a correct JSSE-format example you could have uncommented and modified. It looks like it could be from [the standard one](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/9.0.x/conf/server.xml) although that has _also_ an OpenSSL-format example you don't.

Comment: @SAADK Did you get it to work? What was the correct format with P12 file?